# Sending Email in delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

my problem is this: i try to send an email with delphi 7, but when i try to send it, I get an error.

Maybe is only a problem about TIdSMTP, that it can't connect with a smtps server, but i didn't found another component for send mail with delphi 7.

My code is this one:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  inifiles, Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, IdMessage, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdTCPConnection,
  IdTCPClient, IdMessageClient, IdSMTP, DB, DBTables, ExtCtrls,
  ComCtrls, StdCtrls, Buttons;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    MailMessage: TIdMessage;
    SMTPS: TIdSMTP;
    AttachmentDialog: TOpenDialog;
    Body: TMemo;
    StatusMemo: TMemo;
    Timer1: TTimer;

    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private

  public
    Host : string;
    Port : string;
    Username : string;
    Password : string;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
Host, Username, Password : string;
begin

   Host     := 'smtps.aruba.it'; //Aruba SMTPS Host
   Username := 'xxxx@xxxxxxx.xxx';
   Password := 'yyyyyyyy';

  //setup SMTP
  SMTPS.Host := Host;
  SMTPS.Port := 465;//SMTPS Port of Aruba
  SMTPS.Username := Username;
  SMTPS.Password := Password;

  //setup mail message
  MailMessage.From.Address := 'xxxxx@xxxxxxxx.xxx';

  MailMessage.Subject := 'Subject';
  MailMessage.Body.Text := 'Body Text';

  //send mail
  try
    try
      SMTPS.Connect(1000);
      SMTPS.Send(MailMessage);
    except on E:Exception do
      showmessage(E.message);
    end;
  finally
    if SMTPS.Connected then SMTPS.Disconnect;
  end;

end;

end.
```

The error is this:

**Connection Closed Gracefully**

Comment: The SSL libraries (libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll) are in the project folder? If not, you can download it here: https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/

Comment: You are connecting to the SMTP implicit SSL port, are you setting the `TIdSMTP.UseTLS` property to `utUseImplicitTLS` to match? On that port, an SSL/TLS handshake needs to be negotiated immediately upon connect before any SMTP traffic can then be exchanged. The server will forcibly kick you when it doesn't receive a valid handshake. If you leave `UseTLS` set to its default of `utNoTLSSupport`, `TIdSMTP.Connect` will block waiting for an SMTP greeting that is never sent, and unblock only on an error. What does your `TIdSMTP` configuration actually look like? You did not provide those details.

Comment: Another problem might be that hosting parties are limiting the allowed encryption version TLS 1.2 only and limitting the cyphersuites. Older Indy version dont support these out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem so I wrote an application that finds correct settings for me. Source code for you to look at is https://github.com/Edijus/Email-Settings-Getter
Basically, it loops through all possible `TIdSMTPAuthenticationType, TIdSSLVersion, TIdUseTLS`